# WinSCP: Where can I find the list of successfully transfered files? Like in FileZilla

Tags: winscp

When I transfer files with WinSCP, I only see them while they are being transferred. Once the files are uploaded/downloaded the queue becomes empty and no "history" is available. Am I missing something? Is there a plugin to see successful transfers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure how long the completed transfers display using the [option *Display completed transfer in queue*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_background).

Answer (score 5):

In the menu

> Options => Preferences.. => Logging

you can enable logging. That should give you the history of all the files you transfer.